# Python 2.7 read each line in text file until character

Tags: python-2.7

I'm making a python script where I want to read a text file line by line but stop at a colon on each line and make the text it's read into indiviual strings.

Heres an example of the text file:

Line 1:text1

Line 2:text2

Line 3:text3

I'm very new to python.

Comment: You need to provide example output, not just input. Your description is unclear on whether the data after the colon is preserved as a separate string or discard, and what you want to do with whatever qualifies to be kept. It also helps to show some effort, in the form of a [MCVE]; this is *very* trivial, and asking for us to write it for you when you haven't even tried is frowned upon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try reading each line of the file, and then split by colon to retain just the first portion of each line:

```
with open("input.txt", "r") as ins:
for line in ins:
    print(line.split(":")[0])
```

Answer (score 0):

A quick python 1-liner for storing the strings in a list:

```
lines = [s[:s.find(':')] for s in open('input.txt')]
print lines
```

Hope it helps